# Rationale behind enum access semantics in C++

Tags: c++, enums, language-design

Can someone shed some light on the semantics for accessing an enum defined in a class in C++?

In particular, why are enum members accessed by the name of the class rather than the enum itself? Given that the `enum` is the container/scope, just as `namespace` and `class` are, why is accessing an element of the container treated differently when it's an `enum` than when it's a `class`?

Given

```
namespace mynamespace
{
    class myclass
    {
    public:
        enum myenum
        {
            enum1,
            enum2
        };

        int myint;
    };
}
```

Why is the fully-qualified name for `enum1` `mynamespace::myclass::enum1` and not `mynamespace::myclass::myenum::enum1`?

While the latter "works," it's not the "recommended" way of calling it and some compilers will throw a warning there. IMHO, it should not only be right, but it should also be the only way of accessing it.

It makes for really odd access rules, and makes things very weird when you add a new `enum1` in a different enum (at which point you must add the qualifier).

Really, it defeats the purpose of an enum. The members of the enum are really more members of the class than they are of the enum, and I must say I find the behavior in other languages (e.g. C#) to be much more preferable.

I imagine this is to keep compatibility with C, but I don't see why requiring the enum name in the access semantic would be the better option... I'd imagine making the *class* name optional would be the option that preserves C compatibility.

Comment: I think it is to do with C compatibility, but if should consider using an `enum class` which is added to C++11 they obey the correct semantics`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++03, as in C, an `enum` does not introduce a new scope. The names defined go into the surrounding scope. Which might be a namespace, or a class.

C++11 added scoped enums and based enums.

Ordinary C++03 `enum`:

```
enum Cpp03 { a, b, c };
```

C++11 **based `enum`**:

```
enum Cpp11Based: long { a, b, c };
```

C++11 **scoped `enum`** (which acts as a scope for the names, like in your example):

```
enum class Cpp11Scoped1 { a, b, c };
enum struct Cpp11Scoped2 { a, b, c };
```

The last two forms are equivalent, and allow writing e.g. `Cpp11Scoped1::a`.

Finally, a scoped `enum` can be based (specifying the *underlying type* for the names, i.e. size and signedness):

```
enum class Cpp11ScopedAndBased: long { a, b, c };
```

Some C++03 compilers, including Visual C++, provided the scope functionality also for the ordinary C++03 `enum`.

My guess is that what you have run into, a language extension.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head there. I was originally using scoping with VC++, but have been doing things the "right" way to avoid warnings that I didn't notice it behaved differently on GCC (which I'm currently on).

Comment: Just a note: the correct syntax is `enum class EnumName : int` not `enum class : int EnumName`

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi: Thanks! I'm going to edit the answer (which had incorrect syntax). I just wrote that from off the top of my head, I don't think I have a compiler that accepts this syntax yet, although I think the latest version of g++ does support it, and also probably, clang supports it.

Answer (score 1):

The basic answer is that your "Given that the `enum` is the container/scope" is just plain wrong -- according to C and C++, an `enum` does *not* establish a scope (and is not a container).

In short, `enum whatever { a, b, c};`

isn't a whole lot different from:

```
const int a = 0;
const int b = 1;
const int c = 2;
```

While you can use `enum whatever` to define variables able to hold the values of that type, they're not generally a whole lot different from some integer type capable of holding the right range of values.

Comment: Just a note for readers -- @Jerry I know that you know this: one difference is that in C++, there's no implicit conversion from e.g. `int` to enum value (but there is the other way).