# Access enumerator of an enum formerly declared as protected

Tags: c++

For my project I'd like to widen the visibility of an enum formerly declared as protected in the baseclass.

```
class A { 
protected:
    enum E { e = 0 };
};

class B : public A { 
public:
    using A::E;
};

int main()
{
    B::E enum1; // okay
    enum1 = B::e; // fails: test.cpp:3:14: error: A::E A::e is protected
}
```

The reasons for this are simple:

- I don't control the base class, hence I cannot just make `E` public
- I don't want a huge switch-case statement for translating between a new enum in `B` and `A::E`

I'd expect(ed) the code to compile just fine.

I'm curious. What's the scientific explanation why the code fails to compile?

Comment: *After* posting this I've noticed that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814074/rationale-behind-enum-access-semantics-in-c?rq=1 gives a sufficient good reasoning. Using plain C++03 enum doesn't introduce a new scope, hence the *enumerators* still go to the surrounding scope. Defining "using `A::E`" doesn't change this fact, of course, and just makes the enum itself public, not the names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making `A::E` public doesn't affect the names of the enumerators, so `e` is still protected.

Try with an additional `using` or add a `static const E e = A::e` to class `B`.

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly sane C++ code using C++11's scoping semantics:

```
int main()
{
    B::E enum1; // okay
    enum1 = B::E::e; // also okay
}
```